# How can I modify the index of my pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this python code

```
def get_yahoo(tickers, startdate, enddate):
    from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
    import pandas as pd
    def data(ticker):
        return(pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=startdate, end=enddate))
    datas=map(data,tickers)
    return(pd.concat(datas,keys=tickers,names=['Ticker','Date']))



tickers_example=['MSFT', 'AAPL']
yahoo=get_yahoo(tickers_example, "2017-01-01", "2018-01-01")
```

That is returning a pandas dataframe with this "composed (ticker,date)" index:

[image]

But I need my pandas Dataframe with the index and columns with a format like that:
[image]

How can I get that?

Comment: Try `yahoo.reset_index()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris comment work like a charm:

yahoo.reset_index()